# message passing by variable and "direct" in erlang

Tags: erlang, pid, sendmessage

I read in the book "A Concurrent Approach to Software Development" by O'Reilly
and there is in page 93, a few examples of "Message Passing".

```
1> Pid = self().
<0.30.0>
2> Pid ! hello.
hello
3> <0.30.0> ! hello.
* 1: syntax error before: '<'
```

The problem is that I don't understand why there is a syntax error, since when I type `1> Pid.` 
I get the result `<0.30.0>`, so what's make the difference between line 2, and line 3 (expect from the fact that it's a variable)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending message Pid Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169931/sending-message-pid-erlang)

Comment: I saw this questions, but I'm not asking how to send a message, I'm asking why I can't send it in both of the ways

Comment: Look at the [third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170100/409228) on that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no syntax for literal process ids in Erlang.  The reason for this is that it almost never makes sense: the process you want to reach most likely has a different pid every time your program runs.

Usually you'll spawn a process, save the return value of `spawn` in a variable, and then use that variable to interact with the process.

If you really want to get a usable pid from its string representation, you can use the function `list_to_pid`, or `pid` to get a pid from the printed components:

```
list_to_pid("<0.30.0>")
pid(0,30,0)
```

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I would also add the possible use of `pid(0,30,0)` for example.

Answer (score 4):

Pid is an Erlang data type that displays in the format you see `<0.30.0>`. But that display string isn't automatically converted to the pid data type when you enter it manually.

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html